# Domain's redemptionPeriod duration

Tags: dns

Good afternoon!

I've read some articles about domain's `redemptionPeriod` but still can't find a clear answer. What's the duration of this period? Somebody says 30 days, another assure that 45. Maybe it depends of something parameters like domain registar, zone etc?
I'd like to buy the domain at `.com` and here some information about it:

Status: redemptionPeriod
Updated Date: 04-apr-2012
Creation Date: 24-feb-2009
Expiration Date: 24-feb-2012

So when it will be available for purchase?

And one more question: is it true, that the only way to get it is making a bid at auction? Maybe it's possible to purchase it like a regular domain?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a .com you should have a redemption period of 30 days. During this time the old owner can restore the domain for a premium price. A few days later it will be deleted.

The market for .com is pretty active, so if your desired name has any value attached to it, it will probably be snapped by an auction platform within seconds of being deleted and you will only be able to buy it from them.

Comment: thanks) i was waiting for about 80 days, but the domain was still in redemptionPeriod. But once it was sold to somebody.